# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. Invalid operationsException :

Tags: asp.net-core

Can not scoped service 'ProjName.Contexts.ProductContext' from singleton 'ProjName. Persistence.IProductRepository'

This is the my code:

```
Public void ConfigurationService  (IServiceCollection service )
{
    service. AddDbContext <ProductContext>(options =>UserSqlServer (Configuration. GetConnectionString ("Prdcn")));
    Services. AddSingleton <IPRODUCTREPOSITORY, ProductRepository >(); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Without a well formed question you will not receive any help. This includes but is not limited to an example of your code that shows the problem. Anything else is just laziness,  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not much info to go on so I'll just show you how I register my context and repository for DI.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalMachine"));
    });

    services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyAppDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    //my repository is generic
    services.AddScoped<IRepository<IBaseEntity>, Repository>();

    ...
}
```